# Bash - Multiple replace with sed statement

Tags: bash, unix, sed, replace

I'm getting mad with a script performance.

Basically I have to replace 600 strings in more than 35000 files.

I have got something like this:

```
patterns=(
   oldText1 newText1
   oldText2 newText2
   oldText3 newText3
)

pattern_count=${#patterns[*]}

files=(`find \. -name '*.js'`);
files_count=${#files[*]}

for ((i=0; i < $pattern_count ; i=i+2)); do
    search=${patterns[i]};
    replace=${patterns[i+1]};
    echo -en "\e[0K\r Status "$proggress"%. Iteration: "$i" of " $pattern_count;
    for ((j=0; j < $files_count; j++)); do
        command sed -i s#$search#$replace#g ${files[j]};
        proggress=$(($i*100/$files_count));
        echo -en "\e[0K\r Inside the second loop: " $proggress"%. File: "$j" of "$files_count;
    done
    proggress=$(($i*100/$pattern_count));
    echo -en "\e[0K\r Status "$proggress"%. Iteration: "$i" of " $pattern_count;
done
```

But this takes tons of minutes. There is another solution? Probably using sed just one time and not in a double loop?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can chain replacements with `sed -e` and run multiple processes in parallel by passing the ampersand to these commands, e.g. `sed -e 's/word1/replace1/' -e 's/word2/replace2' &`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a proper `sed` script:

```
s/pattern1/replacement1/g
s/pattern2/replacement2/g
...
```

Run this script with `sed -f script.sed file` (or in whatever way is required).

You may create that `sed` script using your array:

```
printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' "${patterns[@]}" >script.sed
```

Applying it to the files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i -f script.sed {} ';'
```

I don't quite know how GNU `sed` (which I assume you're using) is handling multiple files when you use `-i`, but you may also want to try

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i -f script.sed {} +
```

which may potentially be much more efficient (executing as few `sed` commands as possible).  As always, test on data that you can afford to throw away after testing.

For more information about using `-exec` with `find`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705

Comment: Currently executing this way on the server, it seems that is going so much faster; just one iteration each file, there is no proggress bar but the good part is the performance increase I guess. Thanks a lot @Kusalananda

Comment: @CristianBatista You could insert `-print` before the `-exec` to see what files it finds at least... That would give you an indication of how far it has got. That would produce 35000 lines of output in the terminal though...

Comment: Yes, that will be useful but noticeably slower I guess. I will put the whole time it took at the end

Comment: 35 minutes finally, instead of my 16 hours estimation. You rock

Comment: @CristianBatista Did you use the first or second `find` variation?

Comment: GNU sed with the `-i` option and multiple files operates on a per-file basis, as the option implies the `-s`/`--separate` option.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to run sed multiple times over one file. You can separate sed commands with ';'
2. You can execute multiple seds in parallel

For example:

```
patterns=(
   oldText1 newText1
   oldText2 newText2
   oldText3 newText3
)
// construct sed argument such as 's/old/new/g;s/old2/new2/g;...'
sedarg=$(
for ((i = 0; i < ${#patterns[@]}; i += 2)); do
        echo -n "s/${patterns[i]}/${patterns[i+1]}/g;"
done
)

// find all files named '*.js' and pass them to args with zero as separator
// xargs will parse them:
//  -0 use zero as separator
//  --verbose will print the line before execution (ie. sed -i .... file)
//  -n1 pass one argument/one line to one sed
//  -P8 run 8 seds simulteneusly (experiment with that value, depends on how fast your cpu and harddrive is)
find . -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 --verbose -n1 -P8 sed -i "$sedarg"
```

If you need the progress bar so much, I guess you can count the lines `xargs --verbose` returns or better use `parallel --bar`, see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/576700/tracking-progress-with-xargs).

Comment: I will use this command after the @Kusalananda's one, it's an awesome solution, the -P8 it's interesting, thanks a lot for your input